# Application is killed due to Out of memory in galaxy server

Tags: meteor, server, galaxy

I deployed my meteor app into galaxy server,while working,inbetween server has stopped by saying "Application exited with signal:killed(out of memory)" and again starting and again same error occuring.I increased the size of containers to maximum ,but still no use.Any help and suggestions?.It is showing memory peak less than 90 % ,I can say 50%.

Comment: What's your memory profile on localhost? Is there maybe an unidentified memory leak?

Comment: how to find memory leakage on galaxy server?

Comment: If there is a memory leak it's in your code so you can find it locally, no need to check for ml on Galax.

Comment: Again I am getting same error,so I am not understanding that how to find exact line or file of code where memory leakage is actually happening.

Comment: I passed "TOOL_NODE_FLAGS":"--max-old-space-size=4096"  in settings.json..But still no use